# Monitor could not be set, Winbugs error. How can I fix it?

Tags: winbugs

I am using WinBUGS to to find the posterior distributions of the developed PPoF models uncertain parameters. The code and data are listed below. I ran the code. Model is synthetically correct. The data were loaded. I compiled. Inits were generated. I could set c, n, s as nodes. But when I set m as a node by using sample monitor tool, I got an error message that says "Monitor could not be set". In addition, When I enter * for node, buttons such as density, stats, auto cor do not get darker so I cannot press them.  How can I fix it? Can anyone possibly help me out? Much appreciated!

I used the following code.

```
+model;
{

c~dnorm(2.33E-10, 1.72E19) 
n~dnorm(3.10,0.71) 
m~dunif(1,4) 
s~dunif(0,5)


c <- 1000

for( i in 1 : N ) {
zeros[i] <- 0
L[i] <-(1/(s*pow(2*3.141592654,0.5)))*exp(-0.5*pow(x[i,1]- 
((c*pow(x[i,2],n)*pow(x[i,3]/0.1167,m0))),2)/pow(s,2))

ghr[i] <- ( -1) * log(L[i]) + c 
zeros[i] ~ dpois(ghr[i])
}
tau<-1/pow(s,2) 
e~dnorm(0,tau)

}

}


DATA 
list(N=8,
 m=3.45, 3.2, 2.65, 2.95, 3.067, 3.68,  3.3,  3.76), 
 x = structure(.Data=c(0.00000000311, 0.00000000328, 0.00000000238, 
 0.000000000005, 0.00000000000546,  0.00000000419,  0.00000000137,0), .Dim = 
 c(2,4))        

 list(c=1, n=1, m=1, s=1, e=1)
```